# Multiple form with form-validate-jquery not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, html

In my laravel project I have 3 forms in same page with form-validate-jquery class to validating the form elements. But on click of submit button it always validates the first form only. There are 3 forms when click on second form's submit button or third form's submit buttton it shows the validations on the first form only.

```
{{ Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-validate-jquery','url' => (isset($client_detail)) ? "/clients/$client_id" : "/clients", 'method' => (isset($client_detail)) ? "put" : "post")) }}

            <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">{{ (isset($client_detail)) ? 'Edit' : 'Add' }} Client <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="icon-more"></i></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <fieldset class="content-group">
                    <legend class="text-bold"></legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Client Name: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                    {{ Form:: text('client_name', $client_name, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'placeholder' => 'name', 'maxlength' => '50')) }}
                            </div>            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Client Code: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                           @if(isset($client_detail)) <div><mark>{{$client_code}}</mark></div> @else {{ Form:: text('client_code', $client_code, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '','placeholder' => 'Code', 'maxlength' => '10')) }}@endif
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Exchequer Code: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                           @if(isset($client_detail))<div><mark>{{$exchequer}}</mark></div> @else {{ Form:: text('exchequer', $exchequer, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '','placeholder' => 'Exchequer', 'maxlength' => '10')) }}@endif
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Address1: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            {{ Form:: text('address1', $address1, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Address1', 'maxlength' => '50')) }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Address2:</label>
                            {{ Form:: text('address2', $address2, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Address2', 'maxlength' => '50')) }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Address3:</label>
                           {{ Form:: text('address3', $address3, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Address3', 'maxlength' => '50')) }}</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Town: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                           {{ Form:: text('town', $town, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '','placeholder' => 'Town', 'maxlength' => '10')) }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Country:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-earth"></i></span>
                                    {{ Form:: text('country', $country, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Country', 'maxlength' => '10')) }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Postcode: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            {{ Form:: text('postcode', $postcode, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '','placeholder' => 'Postcode', 'maxlength' => '8')) }}</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Contact Name: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                           {{ Form:: text('contact_name', $contact_name, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '','placeholder' => 'contact Name', 'maxlength' => '20')) }}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Contact Number: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            {{ Form:: number('contact_number', $contact_number, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '','placeholder' => 'contact Number', 'maxlength' => '10')) }}</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Comment:</label>
                           {{ Form:: text('comment', $comment, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Comment', 'maxlength' => '500')) }}</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label >Status: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            {{ Form:: checkbox('status', 'A', ($status=='A')?'1':null,array('id' => 'status', 'class' => 'switch','data-on-text'=>'Yes','data-off-text'=>'No')) }}

                           <!-- {{ Form::select('status', [
                                '' => 'Select',
                                'A' => 'Active',
                                'I' => 'Inactive'],$status,array('class' => 'form-control','required' => '')
                             ) }}--></div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>


            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">Contracts <a class="heading-elements-toggle"><i class="icon-more"></i></a></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                    <fieldset class="content-group">
                    <legend class="text-bold"></legend>
                    <table id="contract_table" class="table" style="width:100%" cellspacing="10px">
                    <thead>
                        <?php 
                        $addModel = 'showAddContractModel_create()';
                        if(isset($contract_detail))
                        {
                            $addModel = "showAddContractModel_edit($client_id)";
                        }
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Contract Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><th>Contract Code<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><th>Contract Type</th><th>Contract Extension Period<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><th>Contract Email<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><th>Start Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th><th>End Date</th><th><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="removebutton" onclick="{{ $addModel }}" class="btn bg-info-300">+Add Contract</a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @if(isset($contract_detail))
                        @if(count($contract_detail))
                            @php ($i=0)
                            @foreach($contract_detail as $contract)
                            @php ($i++ )
                            <tr>
                            <td><input type="hidden" id="hid_contract_id_{{ $contract->id }}" name="contract_id[]" value="{{ $contract->id }}"><input type="hidden" id="hid_contract_name_{{ $contract->id }}" name="contract_name[]" value="{{ $contract->contract_name }}" ><span  id='contract_name_{{ $contract->id }}'>{{ $contract->contract_name }}</span></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" id="hid_contract_code_{{ $contract->id }}" name="contract_code[]" value="{{ $contract->contract_code }}"  ><span  id='contract_code_{{ $contract->id }}'>{{ $contract->contract_code }}</span></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" id="hid_contract_type_{{ $contract->id }}" name="contract_type[]" value="{{ $contract->contract_type }}"><span  id='contract_type_{{ $contract->id }}'>{{ $contract->contract_type }}</span></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" id="hid_contract_ext_period_{{ $contract->id }}" name="contract_ext_period[]" value="{{ $contract->contract_ext_period }}"  ><span  id='contract_ext_period_{{ $contract->id }}'>{{ $contract->contract_ext_period }}</span></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" id="hid_contract_email_{{ $contract->id }}" name="contract_email[]" value="{{ $contract->contract_email }}"  ><span  id='contract_emil_{{ $contract->id }}'>{{ $contract->contract_email }}</span></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" id="hid_startdate_{{ $contract->id }}" name="startdate[]" value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contract->startdate)->format('d-m-Y') }}"  ><span  id='startdate_{{ $contract->id }}'>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contract->startdate)->format('d-m-Y') }}</span></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" id="hid_enddate_{{ $contract->id }}" name="enddate[]" value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contract->enddate)->format('d-m-Y') }}"><span  id='enddate_{{ $contract->id }}'>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($contract->enddate)->format('d-m-Y') }}</span></td>
                            <td><div class="heading-btn-group">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" name="removebutton" onclick="showContractEditModel_edit({{ $contract->id }},'edit')"><i class="icon-pencil7 text-info"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" name="removebutton" onclick="removeContractRow(this,{{ $contract->id }},'{{ $contract->contract_name }}')" ><i class="icon-trash  delete text-danger"></i></a>
                        </div></td>
                        <td><div class="heading-btn-group">
                            <a href="javascript:;" name="addresponse" onclick="showResponse('{!! URL::to('/showResponse') !!}','{{$contract->id}}')" class="btn bg-indigo-300">+</a>
                        </div></td>
                            </tr>

                            @endforeach
                            @else
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan='8' class='text-center'>No data found.</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endif    
                    @endif
                    </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="reset">Reset<i class="icon-reload-alt position-right"></i></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom">Submit<i class="icon-arrow-right14 position-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
            </div>


{{ Form::close() }}

{{ Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-validate-jquery','id' => 'add_response_form')) }}
            {{ Form:: hidden('contract_id', "",array("id"=>"contract_id"))  }}
            <div class="modal-body" id="showResponse_body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="item-add-btn" data-resource="faq" onclick="add_response('{{URL::to('/updateResponse')}}')" >Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}

{{ Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal form-validate-jquery','id' => 'add_item_form')) }}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <fieldset class="content-group">
                        <legend class="text-bold"></legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Contract Name:  <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                {{ Form:: text('contract_name', '', array('id' => 'contract_name', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Contract Name','required' => 'required')) }}
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Contract Code: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                {{ Form:: text('contract_code', '', array('id' => 'contract_code', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Contract Code','required' => 'required')) }}
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Contract Type: </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                {{ Form:: select('contract_type',  [
                                                '' => 'Select',
                                                'A' => 'A',
                                                'B' => 'B'],'',array('id'=>'contract_type', 'class' => 'form-control','title'=>'Please fill out this field')) }}
                            </div>    
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Contract Extension Period: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                {{ Form:: text('contract_ext_period', '', array('id' => 'contract_ext_period', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Contract Extension Period','required' => 'required')) }}
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Contract Email: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-mail-read"></i></span>
                                        {{ Form:: email('contract_email', '',array('id' => 'contract_email', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Contract Email','required' => 'required')) }}
                                </div>        
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Start Date:  <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar3"></i></span>
                                        {{ Form:: text('startdate', '',array('id' => 'startdate', 'class' => 'form-control datepicker', 'placeholder' => 'Start Date','required' => 'required')) }}
                                </div>        
                            </div>    
                        </div>                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-lg-3">End Date:  <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar3"></i></span>
                                        {{ Form:: text('enddate', '', array('id' => 'enddate', 'class' => 'form-control datepicker', 'placeholder' => 'End Date','required' => 'required')) }}
                                </div>        
                            </div>    
                        </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="contract-add-btn" data-resource="faq" onclick="setContractModelToTable(1,'add');" >Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: three forms are same?

Comment: you must have given same id to all the 3 forms so only 1st one is working.. please post your code for clarification..

Comment: How can you be at 700+ reputation and post a question without any code example???

Comment: make the validation with $('#formid').validate() insted of use generic class

Comment: No all the form have different ids .and i dont thik its working on form id.i think it should work for that particular form the button pressed from the form.

Comment: I think you missed the id for your first form..

Comment: ya i missed but i just set it but still no change.

Comment: hello #Fky it works with $('#formid').validate()  but some things are different like it just showing an error but with normal text that "Please fill required fields". There is red color and the icon is missing. what can be the reason behind that? css?

Comment: Ohh the Problem is at a time it works for any one form only.